Variables Switching Values / Position
I am working with a STM32F446RE micro controller, with a LSM6DS3 peripheral attached using SPI, however this should not affect how the C code is run. The functions SPI_READ(), USART2_Write_String and USART2_Write_Num() are working functions and individually produce correct outputs.
int status = SPI_READ(0x1E); // Reads the value of status register
USART2_Write_String("\nHere is status: "); USART2_Write_Num(status); // Outputs status
int data = SPI_READ(0x22); // Reads the value of the LOW_X_G register (low data gyroscope)
USART2_Write_String("\nHere is data: "); USART2_Write_Num(data); // Outputs Status

When the section of code above is run through the MCU I receive:

Here is status: ~50
Here is data: 7

I know these values are reversed as the status register on the LSM6DS3 can only go up to a value of 7, and will consistently read it as I have it taking data samples at 8.33KHz. Along with that the minimum that is ever put in the data register is 20 due to inaccuracy in the sensor.
The functions are defined as:
void USART2_Write_String( char* string ) ;
void USART2_Write_Num( int num ) ;
uint8_t SPI_READ( uint8_t adress ) ; 

I have tried adding ample delay in SPI_READ(), far more than the LSM6DS3's datasheet needs to do a full read and reset but that does not change the result. Neither does changing the order of the reads, they maintain being reversed.
If Needed
LSM6DS3's datasheet

When you say that changing the order of the reads "maintain[s] being reversed", do you mean that you also changed the order of the writes?  Such that the outputs remain associated with the same labels?

The most obvious explanation would be that your code is working as it should.  The unexpected output might in that case result from the arguments to the SPI_READ() calls being reversed, or simply wrong.  In fact, I'm not presently seeing any other likely explanation for the observations you describe, if I understand those correctly.

If you suspect that some kind of memory corruption by some of these functions, then perhaps you could test that by avoiding storing data in memory.  For example: USART2_Write_String("\nHere is status: "); USART2_Write_Num(SPI_READ(0x1E));

Side note: You're using "magic numbers" (e.g. 0x1E and 0x22). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming) There should be an enum or #define in a .h file somewhere (in the SDK) that defines these symbolically (e.g.) #define SPI_STATUS 0x1E and #define SPI_DATA 0x22 So, then you do: int status = SPI_READ(SPI_STATUS); This is cleaner/clearer. Even if you have to create the #define yourself (in the unlikely event they're not defined in a standard .h), it's still better.

To address most comments, the order of the variables that are output are indexed by one, so for instance if I want to output a, b, c it will output c, a, b. I understand that memory corruption is a possibility but watching the MCU sequence through code shows that SPI_READ is output the correct value and that USART2_Write_Num is accepting the correct value. With regard to magic numbers, it makes sense that they would not have meaning without checking the datasheet but a definition for what they mean for me is as good as a comment. I have attempted to add delay between events with no affect.

I found a solution that does seem to work, if I do 2 SPI_READ()'s then the data output to the screen is correct regardless of delay between the reads. Might be a register level issue.

Is MOSI attached to the slave and does writing to it have any effect? Because there is no such thing as "read"/"write" in standard full duplex SPI, there is only transceive, as in read and write all at once.

I would suspect the functions corrupt memory. Remove all function calls to all suspects, create a memory buffer like char membuf[64] and fill it with 0xDA (paint it, so if something gets overwritten, you know what and where was overwritten). Then try using each of those functions, while using &membuf[8] as a buffer starting point. After using one of the functions, check what it did to the memory. Wherever it's not 0xDA, you know it was overwritten, which is also why you don't paint it with zeroes. Make sure that each of those functions operates only on the memory you would expect.
